# MFA Enforcement to Company Administrators Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, multi-factor-authentication

The Company I am working at has an audit.  I just need the code to see the group Company Administrators in Powershell check and validate if they are enforced with MFA authentication or rather make their status enforced.     searched online came up with bits and pieces of the code. pretty new to the Powershell coding so much appreciated if you guys can help with the code I am working as a It Security and Powershell coding is not a part of it

```
Connect-MsolService
#I think this will get company admins
$role = Get-MsolRole -rolename "Company Administrator"

$rm = Get-MsolRoleMember -roleObjectId $role.ObjectId

#not sure what this code is for

foreach ($c in $rm)
{

Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $c.EmailAddress | Select displayname

}
```

Output will be Displayname containing the name
UserPrincipalName will be the email addresses of Company Admins
and MFA status output will be Enforced

this is the other code

```
$role = Get-MsolRole -rolename "Company Administrator"
Get-MsolRoleMember -RoleOBjectId $role.ObjectId
```

Output will display Rolemember type email address Displayname in Ad
and if user is Licensed = true or false

thanks if someone will reply to this

Comment: An EmailAddress is not always the same as the UserPrincipalName. They share the same format, but you can have users with EmailAddress `john.doe@somecompany.com` that have UserPrincipalName `jdoe@somecompany.com`. The code should IMO always check using `Get-ADUser` to obtain the real UserPrincipalName to use with `Get-MsolUser` and `Set-MsolUser`. You can also use the `ObjectId` instead of `UserPrincipalName` for those cmdlets. P.S. the `Get-MsolRoleMember` returns an array of role member objects, hence the `foreach{..}` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot test this myself, so first try it out on a group of test users:

```
# first, get the credentials for a user that is allowed to do this
$cred = Get-Credential
Import-Module MSOnline
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Connect-MsolService –Credential $cred

# set up a StrongAuthenticationRequirement object with the state you want the users in
$requirement = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement
$requirement.RememberDevicesNotIssuedBefore = (Get-Date)
$requirement.RelyingParty = "*"
$requirement.State        = "Enforced"

# get the members of the group (users only)
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Company Administrators' | Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } | ForEach-Object { 
    # get the UserPrincipalName for this user
    $upn = Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName
    $mfa = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn | Select-Object -ExpandProperty StrongAuthenticationRequirements
    if ($mfa.Count -eq 0 -or $mfa[0].State -ne 'Enforced') {
        Write-Host "Enforcing MFA for user $upn"
        Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn -StrongAuthenticationRequirements @($requirement)
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "MFA is already enforced for user $upn"
    }
}
```

Alternative code using `Get-MsolRole` and `Get-MsolRoleMember`

```
# first, get the credentials for a user that is allowed to do this
$cred = Get-Credential
Import-Module MSOnline
Connect-MsolService –Credential $cred

# set up a StrongAuthenticationRequirement object with the state you want the users in
$requirement = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement
$requirement.RememberDevicesNotIssuedBefore = (Get-Date)
$requirement.RelyingParty = "*"
$requirement.State        = "Enforced"

# get a list of administrator roles (possibly only one role object is returned)
$roles = Get-MsolRole -RoleName "Company Administrators"
foreach ($role in $roles) {
    # get the list of members for this role and loop through
    Get-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId $role.ObjectId | ForEach-Object {
        $mfa = Get-MsolUser -ObjectId $_.ObjectId | Select-Object -ExpandProperty StrongAuthenticationRequirements
        if ($mfa.Count -eq 0 -or $mfa[0].State -ne 'Enforced') {
            Write-Host "Enforcing MFA for user $($_.DisplayName)"
            Set-MsolUser -ObjectId $_.ObjectId -StrongAuthenticationRequirements @($requirement)
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "MFA is already enforced for user $($_.DisplayName)"
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

If all you really need is a report of who is in the "Company Administrators" group and their MFA ststus, the code can be much simpler:

```
# first, get the credentials for a user that is allowed to do this
$cred = Get-Credential
Import-Module MSOnline
Connect-MsolService –Credential $cred

# get a list of administrator roles (possibly only one role object is returned)
$roles = Get-MsolRole -RoleName "Company Administrators"
$result = foreach ($role in $roles) {
    # get the list of members for this role and loop through
    Get-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId $role.ObjectId | ForEach-Object {
        $mfa = Get-MsolUser -ObjectId $_.ObjectId | Select-Object -ExpandProperty StrongAuthenticationRequirements
        if ($mfa.Count -eq 0) { $status = 'Disabled' } else { $status = $mfa[0].State }
        # output an object to be collected in variable $result
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'UserName'     = $_.DisplayName
            'EmailAddress' = $_.EmailAddress
            'MFA_Status'   = $status
        }
    }
}

# display on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

#output to a CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\CompanyAdministrators.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Comment: will try this out later and added the sample snippet of code one of the sysadmins used before. output they are needing is the same but I am guessing the code is just cut off or only a part was shown.

Comment: @ChristianGallego Please do not add code snippets as a link to an image of the code. Instead [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58252028/edit) your question and put it in as code-formatted text. Of course, sanitize sensitive information first.

Comment: @ChristianGallego I have added alternative code using only MSOnline cmdlets. Again: as I cannot test this myself try it out on test users or comment out the line `Set-MsolUser ..` during testing.

Comment: my mistake @Theo the Company Administrators just needs to be displayed with MFA status it does not need to be Enforced example if user admin does not have MFA it just needs to be displayed. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ChristianGallego I have updated my answer with code to only retrieve the MFA status.

Comment: Hi @Theo can you call using StrongAuthenticationMethods instead of requirements?

Comment: @ChristianGallego This question started out as a way to enforce MFA. Next it was about _Reporting_ the MFA Status and for both I gave answers. The `StrongAuthenticationMethods` returns information about how MFA is enabled per user, but that is beyond the scope of this question..